# Where did the notify by email option go?

Tags: support, status-completed, email-notification

Today I noticed the checkbox for email notification is gone for new questions. Why did it disappear?

Answer (score 10):

It will be coming back, but it is dying its hair neon green first.

We are in the process of improving the email notifications.  Instead of getting notifications for questions you check the box for and nothing else, email notifications will be driven by your inbox, including comments and other things that are part of the inbox.

We needed to remove the part of the UI you noticed in order to roll this out.  We'll be re-adding a note and link for inbox notifications soon.

In the meantime, if you open your inbox now (where it says Stack Exchange at the upper left and red numbers appear when you have something new), at the bottom of that there is an "email settings" link that allows you to turn on the emails.

*Update:* inbox emails are now live.

Comment: Neon green is such a cool colour.

Comment: Does this also mean that we'll be able to subscribe to be notified in our inbox _without_ getting any emails?

Comment: @hammar I don't understand what you mean?  Currently when you load a page and have something new in the inbox you'll get a red circle with a number indicating the number of new notifications.

Comment: Previously, you used to be able to subscribe to be notified by email when there are new questions in a tag. I'm asking if these changes imply that it will be possible to subscribe to be notified of new questions in your inbox (and only there).

Comment: @hammar ah I see.  Tag filters/subscriptions are completely separate from this.  Nothing is changing with the tag subscriptions.  They aren't going away.