# How to receive email for responses to posts on Stack Overflow

Tags: support, notifications, email

When I post a question on Stack Overflow, I need to avoid having to log back in just to check to see if there is an answer to my post. The Preferences for my user account on Stack Overflow should have an option to select which types of responses send email.

Otherwise, I have to explicitly log back in and check, which is a waste of time. Note that the forum on www.linuxquestions.org has implemented this already, so why can't Stack Overflow implement something similar?

Comment: It's unclear exactly what's motivating you to ask, but if you're unaware: while posting a question, you can click the link labeled *Would you like to have responses to your questions sent to you via email?*

Comment: I subsequently discovered that link you mentioned and used it.  What through me off is how that is presented. The scope of that link was not clear to me, namely, since it was on the page for the question I concluded that it only controlled email notification specifically only for that one question.  What would have been clearer to me is to have the email notificaction control in the per-user global preference page or control panel as the forum software used by LinuxQuestions uses.

Comment: I had to squint at that for a long time before I realised you meant *threw*, not *through*.

Comment: The system disallows me to make edits this long afterwards, otherwise I would correct it.

Answer (score 18):

You can configure your email settings across the whole network by going to the [preferences section of your user profile](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/current) on any site:

[image: email settings in the user profile]

As [Michael Petrotta mentions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107342/how-to-receive-email-for-responses-to-posts-on-stackoverflow#comment-275983), there is a link displayed when asking a new question that will open this screen. Email settings used to be displayed in other locations on the site, but they've been relocated as part of an [overhaul of how email notifications are handled](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106303/where-did-the-notify-by-email-option-go/106307#10630).