# Stack Overflow - Get email notifications

Tags: support, stack-overflow

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to receive email for responses to posts on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107342/how-to-receive-email-for-responses-to-posts-on-stack-overflow)

I want to get an email notification when someone answers or comments on a question I have asked.  (Currently I just refresh over and over).

I've looked through my account setting on S.O. and can't seem to find this option anywhere....am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you open the [MultiCollider SuperDropdown](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66838/158605) in the upper-left of the screen, you'll see an "Email Settings" link on the bottom of the box that will allow you to setup this.

[image]

As an alternative way of getting there, you can also click the "Ask Question" button, and just click the link right above the "Submit Question" button that says *"Would you like to have responses to your questions **sent to you via email**?"*

It should be noted that the only options available are Daily, Weekly, and Every 3 Hours, so this probably won't be a very good substitute for "refreshing the page over and over". If you're looking for a more immediate alert of any new responses, make sure you have Javascript enabled and you should see a little red circle appear by the MultiCollider SuperDropdown when you get a new response.

[image]