# Subscribing to tags - changing the email

Tags: support, email, subscription

I log into SE with my Google Mail account, and I regularly get updates of the form "2 new items in your Stack Exchange inbox" to that account. That's great.

However, when I try to subscribe to a tag I get the following:

[image]

Which would be great - except that's not my email address - mine is joe.reddington@gmail.com not joe.reddingon@gmail.com (missing 't') - my question is, how do I change the address that the superscription is going to? (I'm presuming I was asked for it once and mistyped it...)

EDIT-
Okay - building on hjpotter's answer (which sent me in the right direction but wasn't the key thing)

The problem was that I only appeared to have an 'edit' tap on my stackoverflow profile - all other profiles were 'slaved'(?) to that one...

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/users/edit/170243) I assume. (Profile page --> edit) By default the email field there is set to the one used for the OpenID login but maybe you changed it by mistake at some point.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/107343/158667 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try these steps:

1. Go to [Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com/) website and login.
2. Open your user profile page. it should be [this one](https://stackexchange.com/users/56841/joe).
3. Click on [subscriptions](https://stackexchange.com/users/56841/joe?tab=subscriptions) tab.
4. There should be a link named "manage". Click on it. You'll be presented with a new page where you can edit the email address.

Comment: Accepted but see edit above :)