# Account issue - notifications to old email address

Tags: support, email-notification

At one point or another, I've used 2 email addresses with Stack Overflow - one when I started, and then I updated it as I changed my email address.

The problem is: my notification emails are still going to the old email address, despite the new email address being shown in my profile.

I'm not sure whom to email/write too to try and get this error fixed. The 
[Help Center](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help)
 doesn't seem to cover this issue.

Any ideas please?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107342/how-to-receive-email-for-responses-to-posts-on-stack-overflow/107343#107343 ?

Comment: That is it - some what non-intuitive that it's not in the profile section, but, this is great. Thank you @Mat

Comment: I am running into this problem.  Mail that goes to my personal domain and then forwarded to gmail is bouncing due to domain verification, so I changed my notifications to send directly to gmail.  Despite this, I'm getting several messages per day to the old notification address.  Is the update not global?